# How to write the reg express to get the following pattern in the php?

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match

There is a website and I would like to get all the `<td> (any content) </td>` pattern string

So I write like this:

```
preg_match("/<td>.*</td>/", $web , $matches);
            die(var_dump($matches));
```

That return null, how to fix the problem? Thanks for helping

Comment: Someone told me to never use regex for parsing HTML. Use DOM parser instead :) But if you still need help I can write that regex for u :D

Comment: sure, I need using the php to slove in this case , though I have already sloved it using the jquery

Comment: try non-greedy way `<td>.*?<\/td>`

Comment: Take a close look at the number of `/` you have in your code and why that may be a problem.

Comment: You need to enable dotall mode `(?s)<td>.*?<\/td>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK.

You are only not escaping properly I guess. 
Also use groups to capture your stuff properly.

```
<td>(.*)<\/td>
```

should do. You can try this regex on your given text [here](http://regex101.com/#pcre). Don't forget the **global flag** if you are matching ALL td's. ([preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) in PHP)

Usually parsing HTML with regex is not a good idea, try to use DOM parsers instead.
Example -> http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Test the above regex with

```
$web = file_get_contents('http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp' ); 
preg_match_all("/<td>(.*)<\/td>/", $web , $matches); 
print_r( $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Lazy Quantifier, Different Delimiter**

You need `.*?` rather than `.*`, otherwise you can overshoot the closing `</td>`. Also, your `/` delimiter needed to be escaped when it appeared in `</td>`. We can replace it with another one that doesn't need escaping.

Do this:

```
$regex = '~<td>.*?</td>~';
preg_match_all($regex, $web, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

**Explanation**

- The `~` is just an esthetic tweak—you can use any delimiter you like around your regex patttern, and in general `~` is more versatile than `/`, which needs to be escaped more often, for instance in `</td>`.
- The star quantifier in `.*?` is made "lazy" by the `?` so that the dot only matches as many characters as needed to allow the next token to match (shortest match). Without the `?`, the `.*` first matches the whole string, then backtracks only as far as needed to allow the next token to match (longest match).